# How can I get the default colors in GTK?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

### Context

In GTK 3, people can set their own themes. Even the default theme (Adwaita) is provided with two variants: a light one and a dark one. As I am writing my own widget (in python), I need to get these colors in order to avoid drawing black on black or white on white.

### Question

How can I access the default colors of the user GTK theme?

---

### Things that *don't* work

- `GtkSettings` **used to** provide an acceptable `gtk-theme-color` property, but it is not there anymore and there is no reference in the doc to explain how to replace that.
- I don't want to get that color from another widget:

  - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715464/get-colors-of-current-gtk-style) is of no use: `PyGTK` does not work with Python/GTK 3 and that would require another widget.
  - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506701/how-to-copy-the-gtk-style-of-a-widget-and-apply-it-to-another) would be better (`PyGObject`-based at least) but again, thar would require that I copy the style from another widget.

### Why don't I want to copy the style from another widget?

Because the pristine color is there somewhere. I don't see, in principle, why I should be forced to access it indirectly.

Moreover, how would you react if you crashed a program just because you dared removing a single label somewhere? How would you react if changing the color of a single label actually changed the color of other, completely unrelated, widgets?

I don't want this kind of surprises.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to instantiate GTK widgets to retrieve their `StyleContext`.

You can create an empty [Gtk.StyleContext](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext) and set the [Gtk.WidgetPath](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/WidgetPath.html#Gtk.WidgetPath) of a widget class.

The foreground color can be retrieved with [.get_color()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.get_color).
Other colors and style properties can be retrieved with [.get_property()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.get_property).

Both methods need [Gtk.StateFlags](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/flags.html#Gtk.StateFlags).

For properties, see [GTK+ CSS Overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) and [GTK+ CSS Properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html).

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

# Create an empty style context
style_ctx = Gtk.StyleContext();

# Create an empty widget path
widget_path =  Gtk.WidgetPath();

# Specify the widget class type you want to get colors from
widget_path.append_type(Gtk.Button);
style_ctx.set_path(widget_path);

# Print style context colors of widget class Gtk.Button
print('Gtk.Button: Normal:')
print('foreground color: ', style_ctx.get_color(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL) )
print('color:            ', style_ctx.get_property('color', Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL) )
print('background color: ', style_ctx.get_property('background-color', Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL) )
print('outline color:    ', style_ctx.get_property('outline-color', Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL) )

print('Gtk.Button: Link:')
print('foreground color: ', style_ctx.get_color(Gtk.StateFlags.LINK) )
print('color:            ', style_ctx.get_property('color', Gtk.StateFlags.LINK) )
print('background color: ', style_ctx.get_property('background-color', Gtk.StateFlags.LINK) )
print('outline color:    ', style_ctx.get_property('outline-color', Gtk.StateFlags.LINK) )
```

Answer (score 3):

In your widget's `do_draw()` implementation, you can read out the theme colors from the widget's style context. For this you use methods such as `self.get_style_context().get_color()`, `...get_border_color()`, `...get_background_color()`.

Comment: what about ascent colour?